# Android: Finding/choosing an intent that "shouldn't" be associated with a certain file?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that stores files in getExternalFilesDir(null)... for whatever reason (how other programmers coded their intent filter), not all the apps that I could normally open up for a file if it was in a less nested/non-dotted directory show up as options with this code:

```
intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                try{
                    intent.setType(MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString())));
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    Log.v(TAG, "Mime type="+MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString())));
                    Log.v(TAG, "Uri="+uri.toString());
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.v(TAG, "Uri="+uri.toString());
                    intent.setData(uri);
                }
```

How can I get a listing of the available apps for a certain MIME type, and/or fudge the URI to get around the intent filter (but still pass in the true URI to the app), so I can make a dialog and my user can pick one? Or, is there a builtin way to do this and display the dialog?

Comment: There are over 1.2 million apps on the Play Store, let alone via other channels, pre-installed apps, etc. I feel confident that you have not tested them all. There is no way for you to know that some "fudge the URI" hack will work on all of them. Some will crash with your real `Uri` even if their `<intent-filter>` matched your fudged value. Contact developers of other apps of interest to you and suggest that they fix their `<intent-filter>`. Or, implement a `ContentProvider` to serve the file, as that is the direction that Android is heading, away from `file:///` `Uri` values.

Comment: The ContentProvider sounds smart. I will look into that...

Comment: I'd point you in the direction of `FileProvider` from the SDK, but it does not support `getExternalFilesDir()` as a root, despite what the docs say. [My `StreamProvider` does](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), or you can roll your own.